# Flex Localization Issue for Web Service response result

Tags: apache-flex, localization

In my Flex Application I am receiving Unicode result from back end ( web service) an displaying it in Flex Label component

Eg. Response string = [\u8868\u7af9\uff5eFulfillment~~~~ja]

I am binding response to label component

When I am displaying it in label its not showing me Japanese character .

Storing this information in properties file works
Eg. 
Result.properties
Res=[\u8868\u7af9\uff5eFulfillment~~~~ja]

In side flex component

1. define a metadata tag for Result.properties file
2. call it in Label component as resourceManager.getString(‘Result’,,’Res’)

This show the japaness data in UI

Please provide me with suitable guidance

Answer (score 0):

You can find a pretty good article and sample solution of that problem here: http://www.savage7.com/index.php/2009/08/adobe-flex-3-how-to-create-localized-ui-component-control/

It's bigger than one would have imagined, but it gives you flexibility for future localization changes.